# What's the best datastructure to handle this scenario?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, tree, hashmap

Im being asked to create an app that has a user list which also has expenses linked to the user.

I decided on creating 2 hash tables/dictionaries to handle this, but is there a better way to do this?

I'm thinking maybe theres a better way like using a tree since when I delete an expense from the expenseList, I cannot seem to delete the corresponding expenseId from the userList without iterating through it entirely. Im trying to find a way where I can delete the expense from the userList and expenseList  the most optimal way.

All expenses must also be linked to a user.

Below is the initial datastructure I decided to go with:

```
export const userList = {
  1:  {     
    userId:1,
    firstname:'Jonathan',
    lastname: 'Lee',
    expenseIds: [
      10,
      20,
      30,
      40
    ]
  },
  2:  {     
    userId:2,
    firstname:'Todd',
    lastname: 'Don',
    expenseIds: [
      50
    ]
  }
}; 

export const expenseList = {
    10:{
        userId: 1,
        expId: 10,
        fullname: 'Jonathan Lee',
        category: 'food',
        description: 'had dinner with client',
        cost: 130.31   
    },
    20:{
        userId: 1,
        expId: 20,
        fullname:'Jonathan Lee',
        category: 'travel' ,
        description: 'had dinner with client',
        cost: 50.00
    },
    30:{
      userId: 1,
      expId: 30,
      fullname:'Jonathan Lee',
      category: 'travel' ,
      description: 'travel expenses',
      cost: 150.00
    },
    40:{
      userId: 1,
      expId: 40,
      fullname:'Jonathan Lee',
      category: 'equipment' ,
      description: 'expensing new laptop',
      cost: 1500.00
    },
    50:{
      userId: 2,
      expId: 50,
      fullname:'Todd Don',
      category: 'equipment' ,
      description: 'expensing new laptop',
      cost: 1100.00
    }   };
```

Comment: Why are these even 2 seperate "lists"? Can't you just add the expenses to the user object instead of the expenses reference?

Comment: In a data base perspective, use 2 lists  "Products" and "Users" and a many to many relation between these 2 lists.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a set for managing the list of expenseIds per user:

```
userList = {
  1:  {     
    userId:1,
    firstname:'Jonathan',
    lastname: 'Lee',
    expenseIds: new Set([
      10,
      20,
      30,
      40
    ])
  },
  // ... etc
}
```

So now you don't have to iterate a list, but can do `user.expenseIds.delete(30)`.

So in full:

```js
function deleteExpense(expenseId) {
    const {userId} = expenseList[expenseId];
    userList[userId].expenseIds.delete(expenseId);
    delete expenseList[userId];
}

// Data simplified for this snippet only
const userList = {
  1:  { userId:1, expenseIds: new Set([10,20,30,40]) },
  2:  { userId:2, expenseIds: new Set([50]) }
}; 

const expenseList = {
    10:{ userId: 1 },
    20:{ userId: 1 },
    30:{ userId: 1 },
    40:{ userId: 1 },
    50:{ userId: 2 }
};

deleteExpense(30);
console.log(...userList[1].expenseIds);
```

Comment: Isn't the question that OP doesn't want to iterate over all users?

Comment: @kev, that's not my understanding. They have the userId already when deleting from `expenseList`.  Their question seems to be about performing the mirroring deletion from the first data structure: they can find the user id by key, but then in the child `expenseIds` they have to iterate to find the expense id that needs deletion: *"when I delete an expense from the expenseList, I cannot seem to delete the corresponding expenseId from the userList without iterating through it entirely"*

Comment: Yes you're right!